# Zero downtime deploy to azure as an docker container

Tags: git, azure, deployment, docker, continuous-integration

At the moment i commit, let my build server test and deploy using web deploy to azure.

How can i deploy a docker container to azure like web deploy and keep my site up and running? (AppVeyor)

I have a dockerfile as part of my source code.

Ive tried a virtual machine but i create my docker container manually and my site (multiple instances) is down at deployment time.

It would be awesome to have something like that.

- commit
- test
- create a new docker image
- push the docker image to my docker hub repo
- deploy the container to my azure vm
  using the azure cli

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy a new Docker image to your Azure server it means the old one has to go down and while the new one starts up you'll end up with having some downtime.
As far as I know the only solution for this would be to load balance between the old and the new instances.
There are several good example of doing this online, one of them; https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/734#issuecomment-167392770